# "YOUR CONNECTION IS NOT PRIVATE" error after installing burp certificate on android 8.1.0

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I installed burp certificate on my phone (android 8.1.0) but I keep getting this error **`YOUR CONNECTION IS NOT PRIVATE`** when I try to intercept requests with burp (I followed burpsuite instructions to install)

How I can fix this issue?

[image: YOUR CONNECTION IS NOT PRIVATE]

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the Android version you are running

> Apps that target API Level 24 and above no longer trust user or admin-added CAs for secure connections, by default.

You can read more about it [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html)

So maybe the easiest way to inspect your requests is using a device or an emulator
with an android version lower than 7.0